# How to get standardized betas for regression, with categorical variables in R

Tags: r, regression

I want to get a standardized regression coefficient using lm.beta function. However, when I run the codes, it gave me an error:

> Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
> Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
> Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.

I think it is due to a categorical variable in my model. Then I looked up to the R documentation of Package ‘lm.beta’ [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lm.beta/lm.beta.pdf), when I run the example, I still got the same error. Codes are as follow:

```
## Annette Dobson (1990) "An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models". 
## Page 9: Plant Weight Data.
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
# standardize
lm.D9.beta <- lm.beta(lm.D9)
print(lm.D9.beta)
summary(lm.D9.beta)
coef(lm.D9.beta)
```

I have two questions:

1. Can categorical variables be used in lm.beta function?
2. How to avoid this error?

Appreciated for any suggestions!

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this error.
The code works on my computer, you could try updating R and installed packages.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it's because a variable is categorical in your regression model.

I think if you add `as.numeric(x)` — with `x` being a factor in the `lm` equation — before applying `lm.beta`, it should work fine.